# SQL/PHP - Between Query with time() function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, between

I'm trying to select the users from my table between two Unix dates. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but it throws an error. I'm also using Yii Framework.

My idea is to select users created in the last 30 minutes up to the current time.

This is what I'm doing.

```
public function actionIndex() {
        $model = Cotizacion::find();
        ->where(['created_at' BETWEEN time() - (30 * 60) AND time()])
        ->all();
        $this->layout = false;
        return $this->render('index', ['actionIndex' => $model]);
    }
```

The column name is "created_at". I have seen similar questions, but none of the answers to those questions worked. I would appreciate any help. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes in the where clause are off.  Try changing them to be this:

```
   ->where(["'created_at' BETWEEN ".time()." - (30 * 60) AND ". time()])
```

Comment: It worked finally by doing ->where(['between', 'created_at', time() - (30 * 60), time()]). Thanks for your help!